# Change the translation language programmatically in magento

Tags: php, magento

I created a module that send an email with a pdf attachment when a customer selects a specific  payment type. You can resend the email with the attachment in the back-end. The pdf sent automatically is translated in the correct shop default language. But when I manually resend the email with the pdf I can't figure out how to change in which language the pdf will be translated.

I can change the email template that is used with:

```
$local = Mage::getStoreConfig('general/locale/code', $storeId)
$emailTemplate->loadDefault('my_email_template', $local);
```

I have tried to change the local code:

```
Mage::app()->getLocale()->setLocaleCode($local);
```

The local code change , but it does not translate it in the correct language.
How can I set to which language it must be translated?

Thank you!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try store view emulation.

You can wrap a code you need to be translated into another language with emulation. It would look like this:

```
$enulatedStore = Mage::getSingleton('core/app_emulation');
$inivitalEnvSettings = $emulatedStore->startEnvironmentEmulation($storeId);

//here goes your code. It's going to be run as if it was your store view

$emulatedStore->stopEnvironmentEmulation($inivitalEnvSettings);
```

Emulation means that you switch a store view for a moment. Magento will load all its settings and configuration and design, etc. It's very handy, especially when you want to render a frontend page in admin.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but I already did it with 'Mage::getSingleton('core/translate')->setLocale($local)->init('frontend', true);'

Comment: Indeed, that will help, but it's going to change the locale for the rest of the request. So if there are errors on front, a customer may get message in different language. You should revert such changes after you're done. Cheers

Comment: Thanks, i will change the local back after the request is finished, thank you again